# Working with images in android app development

Tags: android, android-layout

Very much a newbie question here but I cannot find a clear answer on the net or in the books I have. I am designing an app to be compatible with all sizes of android devices and I want to display a images in my app. I understand that android automatically scales images to suit the resolution of the screen being displayed.

My question is what do I look for in the images I use? E.g. I have a picture that's 2418 x 2192 @ 240dpi. As far as I can tell, this should be perfect for a larger screen such as a tablet. If I put this into the xhdpi image folder in my project will it be detected by other devices and scaled to suit their dimensions/resolutions? Do I have to create 3 different versions of this image in photoshop and put it into the relevant dpi folders?

I can't find a nice beginners tutorial for this stuff so haven't a clue what I'm doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best place to start for multiple screen size support:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

The short answer is, yes, you place the images in the different directories based on resolution and Android will select which image to use based on the device's properties. You should make a smaller set of images, for example, for mdpi and hdpi. You don't "have to" do that, and if you just place the image into drawable it can be scaled down, but that's generally not the best way to go.

Comment: I have been looking at that resource you pointed out and I understand the need for resizing but there are no guidelines there for what basic characteristics an image should have other than the dpi. 120dpi for budget devices and 240dpi for high res devices. What dimensions should these images be however? I just can't make sense of it!

Comment: That depends how big you want the image to be on the screen. Here's the relevant section from the article that discusses it: 

"To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:

36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density"

Comment: this might be a dumb question now but if my original image is 48x48 and I scale it to 96x96 won't it be very low quality? Surely it would be better to have a 96x96 image to begin with and scale down?

Comment: Also, px = dp * (dpi / 160). XLarge screens start at 960dp x 720dp, so if you were targeting devices with a 240dpi X-large screen and wanted an image to fill the entire screen, it would be 960*(240/160) and 720*(240/160), which equals 1440 x 1080. I think this is the root of what you're asking.

Comment: Right, you wouldn't want to scale the 48x48 image up. You'd want to provide an alternative 96x96 resource instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you'll deal with on just about all project, because there simply are so many Android devices. [This resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has helped me greatly.

If you have a resource in only ONE folder, Android will scale it for you. The different drawable folders are intended to allow the developer to provide properly scaled images with minimal effort. For example, you'll want to provide an xhdpi in addition to the "standard" mdpi image to make assets look better on high-resolution devices. The app would work fine (and have scaled images) in all resolutions, even if you provided only a single image. However, if you provided a xhdpi drawable, then there's a bit of overhead to scale all of those down, and especially for icons, the results may not look very good (or even be recognizable).

I generally provide assets for mdpi and xhdpi, but if the app will see frequent use on low-res devices, I provide the ldpi as well. If possible, I include all four.

Note: The image you mention is much too large to be included in the UI resources and would probably best be placed in assets and loaded on request. Even on xhdpi devices, it would have to be scaled down.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What would be considered a 'good image' so? I know the image I referenced is quite large. What dimensions should I be looking for? If I wanted an image to suit a Galaxy Tab 10.1' tablet, a Galaxy SII, and a HTC Wildfire for example. That would require 3 different versions of the same image correct? What dimensions should each be approximately? Like I said, really lost with this stuff.